# Will the MySQL datetime format work with SQLite and PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, postgresql, date

In MySQL you enter dates (`datetime` field) in the format `2009-10-16 21:30:45`. Which makes it simple to insert times into the database.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Will this format work with SQLite and PostgreSQL? If not, what format do they use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite uses [several date formats](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html); PostgreSQL uses [similar formats](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) and more.

Both understand YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

Answer (score 2):

[Yes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#AEN5357) for Postgres.

Comment: The content of the page of the link is quite a bit. A small synopsis would help in finding the right information.

Answer (score 1):

As Sqlite doesn't support different data types, yes you can definitely use it. iso-8601 dates have the big advantage that they sort lexically (unlike, for example, US dates)

Comment: SQLite does support different data types, including nulls, numbers, strings, floats, blobs, etc.